# When i press the button it always toast null

Tags: android

Everytime i click button it toast null, i tried replacing result in new instance with string but it returns null.

```
public class Buy extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.buy, container, false);
        Button b = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.press);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.press:
                if (getArguments() != null) {
                    String mParam1 = getArguments().getString("ARG_PARAM1");
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), mParam1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    public static Buy newInstance(String result) {
        Buy fragment = new Buy();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("ARG_PARAM1",result);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
}
```

I want to send String from BackgroundTask1 class to class Buy and display that String when button click. i check result but its not null when i toast it. but when i diplay it in Buy class it displays null.

```
  public class BackgroundTask1 extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
        Context ctx;
        String data;

        // AlertDialog alertDialog;
        public BackgroundTask1(Context ctx) {
            this.ctx = ctx;
        }
       @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
           /* alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Login Information..");*/
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String store_url = "http://192.168.0.108//webapp/store.php";//
            String type = params[0];
            if (type.equals("store")) {
                String Bookname1 = params[1];
                String Bookcondition1 = params[2];
                String Postdate1 = params[3];
                String Expirydate1 = params[4];
                String Description1 = params[5];
                String Sellername1 = params[6];
                String Sellerlocation1 = params[7];
                String Sellercontact1 = params[8];

                try {
                    URL url = new URL(store_url);
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));
                    String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("Bookname1", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Bookname1, "UTF-8") + "&"
                            + URLEncoder.encode("Bookcondition1", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Bookcondition1, "UTF-8") + "&"
                            + URLEncoder.encode("Postdate1", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Postdate1, "UTF-8") + "&"
                            + URLEncoder.encode("Expirydate1", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Expirydate1, "UTF-8") + "&"
                            + URLEncoder.encode("Description1", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Description1, "UTF-8") + "&"
                            + URLEncoder.encode("Sellername1", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Sellername1, "UTF-8") + "&"
                            + URLEncoder.encode("Sellerlocation1", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Sellerlocation1, "UTF-8") + "&"
                            + URLEncoder.encode("Sellercontact1", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Sellercontact1, "UTF-8") + "&";
                    bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                    bufferedWriter.flush();
                    bufferedWriter.close();
                    OS.close();
                    InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(IS, "iso-8859-1"));
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String result = "";
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result += line;
                    }
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                    IS.close();
                    return result; //"Posted Successfully..."

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // e.printStackTrace();
                    return "exception";
                }
            }

            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (result.equals("Posted Successfully...")) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // Intent i=new Intent(this,Sell.class);
            } else if (result.equals("nullpointer")) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Buy fragment = Buy.newInstance(result);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: How are you adding arguments while opening the Fragment. Can you also add your setArguments score? Also what happens if you place this code in your onCreateView rather than onclick? Are your arguments null there as well?

Comment: getArguments() is always getting null value. can you please check if the code has some faults.

Comment: are you calling your fragment like this: Buy. newInstance("result"); ?

Comment: actually i want to send string from one class to another class which extends fragment and display that string during button click.

Comment: In this code, all right, if u create fragment with newInstance("someString") and use onClick in this fragment. Can you show a bit more?

Comment: Please, Could you show us how you are calling the Buy fragment?

Comment: Buy fragment = Buy.newInstance(result);

Comment: Firstly, try to check your "result" before create newInstance. It is not null?

Comment: ya, the result is not null, i've checked it.

Comment: Well, as I said, in the above code everything is right, if you use it correctly. Need more information

Comment: but where is  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container, fragment).commit(); code?

Comment: where should it put that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't call the fragment manager to put the fragment on the screen, you just create its instance.
Try to add callback in `onPostExecute` method.

In your fragment create this:

```
public interface FragmentCallback {
    public void onTaskDone(String result);
}
```

In your activity add this listener in `AsyncTask` constructor signature:

```
new BackgroundTask1(this, new Buy.FragmentCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onTaskDone(String result) {
        Buy fragment = Buy.newInstance(result);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
           .add(R.id.place_for_ur_fragment, fragment).commit();
    }
}).execute();
```

Create callback var in `AsynkTask`, change constructor and `onPostExecute` method:

```
private Buy.FragmentCallback mFragmentCallback;

public BackgroundTask1(Context ctx, Buy.FragmentCallback fragmentCallback) {
    mFragmentCallback = fragmentCallback;
    this.ctx = ctx;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    mFragmentCallback.onTaskDone(result);
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: error: cannot find symbol method getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: Does your Activity extend AppCompatActivity?